# How To Make A VS Code Extension In Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I Use Python As My Main Language, And I Want To Make A VS Code Extension, But I Cant Find Any Docs/Resources, Is Possible To Make One In Python?

Comment: No, because VSC extensions are in JavaScript

Answer (score 6):

VS Code is built on Electron framework which run with Node.js, so it's impossible to make a extension "directly" using Python. However you can use these two ways to keep your stuff mainly in Python:

- Node.js allows you to call outside scripts using [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). it is often used to achieve multi-threading in Node.js.
- If you are developing a language extension, you should give [Language Server](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide) with [LSP](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) a try. By doing this you can start up a server written by Python and communicate with VSC JS client using LSP.

Note that both ways requires you to write some JS/TS code.

Answer (score 3):

VS Code has official documentation on using the Langugage Server/LSP to create a python extension: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/python-extension-template

If you prefer to use the `child_process` approach, there is an unofficial python wrapper: https://github.com/CodeWithSwastik/vscode-ext?u=t&m=o#example-extension